# Aks vm seems to have a very low adjustable vm.max_map_count max at 262144 is that an issue for MongoDB requesting 1677720 by a factor of 6.4

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, azure-aks, virtual-memory

This is from my mongodb replicaset output in AKS. I adjusted it [per the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/custom-node-configuration) but it seems like that is way off. What could this do negatively in running a mongodb server?

```json
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-24T21:20:18.721+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5123300, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"vm.max_map_count is too low","attr":{"currentValue":262144,"recommendedMinimum":1677720,"maxConns":838860},"tags":["startupWarnings"]}
```

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but to infrastructure and mongodb-configuration, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi @Turing85 So, I'm going to have to disagree with you but I understand the point it's just complicated. Here's what I mean. Kubernetes is very complicated. Very. And, posting on DevOps or Server Fault seems like not a place for that. Where is the home for Kubernetes / Docker? To me, and increasingly in the future this will become more and more of a topic as Kubernetes becomes ever so slightly more friendly to use. Is it really that bad that Kube questions are here on Stack? Perhaps a container stack would be best. It does thread the line don't you think.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "catch-all" for things not covered by other StackExchange-Sites. As pointed out on [help/op-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), all questions must be specifically about programming or programming-related. In my opinion, this one is not and is therefore off-topic.

Comment: The programming is in the configuration file. If I edit it to show the configuration would then that be more suited for the label of programming. To me that would be equivalent to webpack or jfrog or jenkins or any other configuration for programming.